# Telegram bot keyboard

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot

Делаю клавиатуру средствами фреймворка, вот кусок кода

```
$available_buttons =ReportToAbonent::select("report_id")
    ->join("telegram.reports", "report_to_abonent.report_id", "=", "reports.id")
    ->where("abonent_id", "=", $abonent[0]->id)
    ->where("active","=","1")
    ->get();

$keyboard = array();
foreach ($available_buttons as $value)
{
    $keyboard[] = array($value->report_id);
}

$reply_markup = \Telegram::replyKeyboardMarkup([
    'keyboard' => $keyboard,
    'resize_keyboard' => true,
    'one_time_keyboard' => false
]);
```

Если распечатать массив `keyboard`, то получается схожая структура массива, как если бы в `keyboard` записать

```
$keyboard = [
    ['7', '8', '9'],
    ['4', '5', '6'],
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['0']
];
```

Однако во втором случае клавиатура рендерится, а первом нет.

Comment: а где первый случай, а где второй?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась приведением типа `$keyboard[] = array((string)$value->report_id);`